# What is a newspaper 段, exactly?

Tags: counters

Does this bit contain 2段, for instance?

[image: image of a text with multiple 段]

Would 3段抜き refer to a write-up containing 3 such 段?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your picture contains 5段【だん】. In other words, this picture is 5段【だん】組【ぐみ】のレイアウト.

段【だん】抜【ぬ】き refers to a long heading or figure which spans multiple 段.

In your example, the purple heading with "日本語組版の特徴と事例" is called 2段抜きの見出し, and the other one is 3段抜き.

Reference: [Adobe InDesign CS5 段抜き見出し](http://study-room.info/id/studyroom/cs5/study14.html)