# What is this kind of book layout called?

Tags: word-requests

That may be off topic, but what is this two-row book layout called in Japanese? And to what extent is this format common?

[image: double-row book]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This layout technique is called 段組み【だんぐみ】, or specifically 2段組み (two-column layout). 段落 (paragraph) is a different concept.

- [What is a newspaper 段, exactly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23054/5010)

Newspapers and magazines almost always use multiple-column layout. It's not very common in novels, but we sometimes see this layout especially when it's a long, hard-covered one with a lot of short lines.

Comment: Many periodicals published by government and academic organizations also follow this format. I just skimmed through some today, including the 学士会会報.